# How do I find if any names in a list of names appears in a paragraph with ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, parsing, coldfusion

Assume that I have a list of employee names from a database (thousands, potentially tens-of-thousands in the near future). To make the problem simpler assume that each firstname/lastname combination is unique (a big if, but a tangent).

I also have a RSS stream of news content that pertains to the business (again, could be in the hundreds of items per day).

What I would like to do is detect if an employees name appears in the several paragraph news item and, if so, 'tag' the item with the person its talking about.

There may be more than one employee named in a single news item so breaking the loop after the first positive match isn't a possibility.

I can certainly brute force things: for every news item, loop over each and every employee name and if a regex expression returns a match, make note of it.

Is there a simpler way in ColdFusion or should I just get on with my nested loops?

Comment: If an employee is mentioned in an article is it by first name AND last name? E.g. "Vanessa Smith likes walnuts" or can it be just the first name "Vanessa likes walnuts"?

Comment: To keep the problem set simple, lets assume that each name will be used in a professional context at least once in the article - in other words both first name and last name (ie "Vanessa Smith") will appear at least once together in the news article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just throwing this out there as something you *could* do...

It sounds like you'll almost unanimously have significantly more employee names than words per post. Here's how I might handle it:

Have an always-running CF app that will pull in the feeds and onAppStart

1. Grab all employees from your db
2. Create an app-scoped look up struct with first names as keys and a struct of last names as values ( you could also add middle names sibling to last names with a 3rd tier if desired ).

So one key in the look up might be "Vanessa" with a struct with 2 keys ( "Johnson" and "Forta" ) as its value.

Then, each article you parse, just listToArray with a space as a delimiter and loop through the array doing a simple structKeyExists with each token. For matches, check the next item in the array as a last name.

I'd *guess* this would be much more performant processingwise than doing however many searches and also take almost no time to code and you can feed in any future sources extremely simply ( your checker takes one argument, any text on Earth ).

Interested to see what route you go and whether your experiments expose anything new about performance in CF.

Comment: Just finished implementing. There was a bit of regex'ing required in order to insure (1) we had valid characters for a struct key name and [T.J. isn't a valid variable name] and (2) that punctuation wasn't causing failures [ 'Lady Luck' not being found in a space delimited list where the sentence is 'She said her name was "Lady Luck"]. Otherwise the proposed Keylist lookup runs incredibly fast and is generic enough to work for numerous sources. **Thanks**!

Comment: That whole thing about [what constitutes a valid variable name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html) has kinda been obsolete since CFMX6.  Using associative array notation, a variable name can be *anything*, so you probably can optimise your code slightly there by *not* sanitising the way names are stored in the struct keys. @David: nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, you have a tall order there, and there are really multiple parts to the challenge/solution. But just in terms of comparing a list of values to a given set of text to see if one of them occur in there, you'll find that there's no one could CF function. BEcause of that, I created a new one, findList, available at cflib:

http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=1908

It's not perfect, nor as optimal as it could be, but it may be a useful first step or you, or give you some ideas. That said, it suited my need (determine if a given blog comment had reference to any of the blacklisted words). I show it comparing a list of URLs, but it could be any words at all. Hope that's a little helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option worth exploring is leveraging the Solr engine that ships with CF now. It will do the string search heavy lifting for you and you can probably focus on dynamically keeping your collections up to date and optimized as new feed items come in.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, Solr would be the optimal long-term solution. But for this prototype I'm looking to do as much "in engine" as possible before going down the path of tuning indexes.

Comment: @MatthewReinbold solr is a component of CF9+

Comment: @Antony I understand solr is included with CF9. I was looking for a solution with the native language constructs first.